# Represent the type Func<dynamic, object> via reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, .net-standard-2.0

Given this method signature:

```
void Foo<T>(Func<T, object> expression)
```

Is it possible to use reflection to create a type-representation of `Func<dynamic, object>` to use with `MakeGenericType` for the `expression` argument's type? The "obvious" approaches are not valid C# syntax because `dynamic` is neither a type nor an object (ie. `typeof(dynamic)` is invalid), so I've not been able to come up with anything useful for the `???` parameter below:

```
Type fnType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { ???, typeof(object) });
```

Interestingly, I *can* do this and it compiles without errors, but the script compiler throws at runtime, I think because that `typeof` is really returning a `Func<object, object>`:

```
Type fn = typeof(Func<dynamic, object>);
```

At least, anything I can find through reflection or the debugger seems indistinguishable from `typeof(Func<object, object>)`. Of course, I realize `dynamic` is a special case in the C# language -- behind-the-scenes black-box "magic" behavior somehow attached to an `object`. The question, I suppose, is what makes that `object` special when I write something like this:

```
Foo<dynamic>(n => new { n.prop });
```

Since `dynamic` tends to generate a flurry of "your architecture sucks" replies, I'll preempt those by explaining the real-world scenario: I'm using the Roslyn Scripting API to load and compile expression delegates from configuration to filter, destructure, or otherwise alter various objects (including anonymous types, hence `dynamic`) written to a structured logger (Serilog).

I am starting to think this is an edge-case that reflection just can't handle. (I've been hoping to avoid Expressions, but I'm wondering if that could pull it off somehow.)

### Edit: Real Code

Sample inputs (that actually work) might be `Sample.Account` (a class in my test console program) and `a => new { a.Username }` as the transformation expression to compile, demonstrating a common structured-logging example of an account class storing a username and password, and you use destructuring to strip the password. (I've already populated `ScriptingOptions` with the necessary assembly references and imports before this is called.)

The output from this (using the inputs described above) would be an instance of `Func<Sample.Account, object>`. The question is how to do this sort of thing to obtain `Func<dynamic, object>` as the output (which can be written and compiled as source, but as far as I can tell, can't be set up through reflection).

```
private static dynamic CompileTransformation(string transformedType, string transformation)
{
    // get a Type that corresponds to namespace.type in transformedType
    Type TValue = Type.GetType(transformedType) ??
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Select(a => a.GetType(transformedType))
        .FirstOrDefault(t => t != null);

    // get a representation of Func<TValue, object>
    Type funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { TValue, typeof(object) });

    // get a representation of CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Func<TValue, object>>()
    var evalMethod = typeof(CSharpScript).GetMethods()
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name.Equals("EvaluateAsync") && m.IsGenericMethod)
        .MakeGenericMethod(funcType);

    // execute EvaluateAsync
    dynamic evalTask = evalMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { transformation, ReflectionHelper.scriptOptions, null, null, null });
    dynamic compiledFunc = evalTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    return compiledFunc;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `typeof(ExpandoObject)` for your `???` - I doubt it will work but worth checking...? Regardless, please could you update the question with an MVCE (yes - a non-compiling one with a placeholder marked as `???`) so that we can try out solutions (and more easily understand the exact nature of your question) ourselves before suggesting them :)

Comment: Worth explaining (with simple example code) what you are trying to achieve. Dynamic (as a "type") is compile time thing, you cannot create it at runtime (I'd even say that this, as a concept, doesn't make sense).

Comment: @RB I'm not sure `ExpandoObject` would fill the bill... the object isn't always an anonymous type, and if I remember correctly, one of the other things `dynamic` can do is (somehow) act as a wrapper around a concrete type (sounds sort of like boxing-for-objects).

Comment: @Evk I understand that, but there must be _something_ that "marks" the resulting `object` as "dynamic-capable" for lack of a better term. So in effect, I'm looking for a way to do the same thing at runtime. I won't be too surprised if it simply isn't possible, but I wanted a more authoritative answer than, "I couldn't figure it out." :)

Comment: Still cannot quite understand your goal. Your code sample works as expected? If not - what is expected?

Comment: @Evk I added another explanatory paragraph before the code.

Comment: If it helps to understand: aside from one attribute, `Func<dynamic, object> M() => n => new { n.prop };` compiles to the exact same IL as `Func<object, object> M() => n => new { ((dynamic) n).prop };`. `dynamic` property access is implemented by calls to the DLR and is completely different from the direct property access using reflection you're used to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to do that via reflection, because `dynamic` concept only exists at compile time, not a run time.

If you compile something like:

```
dynamic x = "test";
Console.WriteLine(x.Length);
```

And decompile result in something like DotPeek - you'll see quite a bunch of cryptic, reflection-like code to which compiler has converted your `dynamic` code. And `x` is really of type `object`, so the whole thing is basically similar to `typeof(string).GetProperty("Length").GetValue(x)`, but maybe more effective. But nowhere you will see any trace of `dynamic` itself.

So, there is no way to somehow obtain `Func<dynamic, object>` from `Func<T, object>` at runtime.

```
Foo<dynamic>(n => new { n.prop });
```

Is conceptually similar to something like:

```
Foo<object>((object n) => new { prop = n.GetType().GetProperty("prop").GetValue(n) });
```

I've unfortunately didn't quite understood your use case, though I tried, so cannot give reasonable advice about what to use instead.

Comment: I suppose the "reflection-like code" is interaction with the dynamic language runtime as mentioned by user hvd in the comments after the question? Makes sense. Good enough as a better explanation than "I just can't get it to work!"

Comment: @McGuireV10 in certain sense. It uses types from `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`, such as `CallSite`, `Binder` and so on. With certain efforts you can manually write such code, and mimic behavior of compiler.